# CoffeeScript in server/server.coffee won't execute

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript

Is there something I have to set up to create a Meteor app using CoffeeScript? I'm doing a simple

Shouldn't server/server.coffee with

```
if Meteor.isServer
  console.log 'hey'
```

work? It won't log for some reason. In the same app I have packages using CoffeeScript working.

(server/server.js with

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  console.log('hey');
}
```

works.)

(Using Meteor 0.9.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have CoffeeScript files work in your application, you'll need to do:

```
$ meteor add coffeescript
```

Packages do something similar with:

```
api.use('coffeescript');
```

Even though a package may depend on `coffeescript`, it won't be exposed to your main app without the `meteor add`.

Comment: Way too obvious! Thanks. :)